# Form populated via API using Jquery/JS and need to set return post value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have integrated into a third party delivery service which I populate via Jquery.

```
[town] -> dropdown
[suburb] -> dropdown
```

On page load all the select elements are blank. When the user selects town, it then populates suburb.

Now in the event of a post to the server and a returned error, I want to set the form to the state the form was posted in by adding a select element to the correct drop down values.

As an example, user selects town_id 5 and suburb_id 105, form is posted, and returned due to an error. At this point I wish to populate town with value 5 and suburb with value 105...

HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    Your town<span class="require">*</span>
        <select name="town_id" id="mds_towns">
            <option value="">Select your town</option>
            <option value="2">Town1</option>
            <option value="3">Town2</option>
            <option value="4">Town3</option>
        </select>...

<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    Your town<span class="require">*</span>
        <select name="suburb_id" id="mds_towns">
            <option value="">Select your suburb</option>
            <option value="2">Suburb1</option>
            <option value="3">Suburb2</option>
            <option value="4">Suburb3</option>
        </select>...
```

I am no jquery expert and I am struggling with the concept of how to get the correct values on a return post.

One of my ideas was to have a special span element with each form field, so something like:

```
<span id="suburb_value" value="105"> <-----------------*** ADD THIS ***
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    Your town<span class="require">*</span>
        <select name="suburb_id" id="mds_towns">
            <option value="">Select your suburb</option>
            <option value="2">Suburb1</option>
            <option value="3">Suburb2</option>
            <option value="4">Suburb3</option>
        </select>...
```

Now when the page loads, I populate the span field via php

```
<span id="suburb_value" value="<?=$suburb_id;?>">
```

Next the javascript does an ajax call to the api and returns with the list of towns. I then check the value in the span fields and if a value is found, I add a select element to the associated select value...

Would this be on the right path?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var townId = <?= (isset($_POST['town_id'])) ? (int) $_POST['town_id'] : 0; ?>,
        suburbId = <?= (isset($_POST['suburb_id'])) ? (int) $_POST['suburb_id'] : 0; ?>;

    if (townId > 0 || suburbId > 0) {
        // make your api call here with townId and suburbId
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you simply want to retain the selected values in the dropdowns after the page is reloaded on submit. In this case, using jQuery you could try something like:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var town_id, suburb_id = false;

    // Here we assign values to these JS variables if they come through via PHP's $_REQUEST.
    <?php echo (!empty($_REQUEST['town_id']) ? 'town_id = '.intval($_REQUEST['town_id']).';' : '') ?>
    <?php echo (!empty($_REQUEST['suburb_id']) ? 'suburb_id = '.intval($_REQUEST['suburb_id']).';' : '') ?>

    // Here we make the correspondings dropdown options selected, if needed.
    if (town_id !== false) {
        $('select[name=town_id] option[value='+  town_id +']').attr('selected', 1);
    }
    if (suburb_id !== false) {
        $('select[name=suburb_id] option[value='+  suburb_id +']').attr('selected', 1);
    }
});
</script>
```

More elegant way of doing this would be to pre-select the OPTIONs while outputting the page via PHP, but it's hard to suggest anything in this regard not knowing the structure of your application.